# python subprocess with hma

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am trying to get subprocess to run an hma proxy through linux. I'm new to Python so maybe I'm not using the right approach. What I need it to do is run hma in the background and have the program check whether or not my public IP is the same as before the program was launched and if it isn't re-run the hma program every 30 minutes.

Basically the program needs to check current IP then connect to hma. If first IP matches second IP, i.e. hma hasn't connected, then print waiting. If the IP doesn't match then run hma again in 30 minutes. Here is the code I have so far.

```
import os
import webbrowser
import time
import socket
import urllib2
import subprocess

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp")
internal = response.read()
print "Internal IP Address is ", internal   
hma = ['cd', '/Desktop/hma', ';', './hma-start', '-r']
subprocess.Popen(hma, shell=True)
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp")
external = response.read()
while (internal == external):
    time.sleep(1)
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp")
    external = response.read()
    print 'waiting'

while (internal != external):
    print 'It changed'
    hma = ['cd', '/Desktop/hma', ';', './hma-start', '-r']
    subprocess.Popen(hma, shell=True)
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp")
    external = response.read()

print "External IP Address is ", external
```

What am I doing wrong? Sorry if this is completely wrong. I'm new to the subprocess module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi so I'm not familiar with hma, but something like this should work.
If not dav1d said make sure hma-start is in your path. I'm not quite sure why your using /Desktop/hma? It shouldn't matter where it is when you have elevated privs.

```
import os
import webbrowser
import time
import socket
import urllib2
import subprocess
import socket

URL = "http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp"
DIR = '/Desktop/hma'
HMA = ['./hma-start', '-r']
WAIT_TIME = 60 * 30 # 30 min
GET_IP = lambda: urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    external = internal = GET_IP()
    print "Internal IP Address is %s" % internal
    try:
        os.chdir(DIR)
    except OSError:
        print "%s not found" % DIR

    print "External IP Address is ", external
    while True:
        external = GET_IP()
        if external != internal:
            print "Proxied"
            time.sleep(WAIT_TIME)
        else:
            print "Not Proxied"
            proc = subprocess.Popen(HMA)
            proc.wait()
```

Comment: This works but after HMA is done connecting it doesn't execute the time.sleep(WAIT_TIME).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `shell=True` your commandline must be a string:

```
hma = 'cd /Desktop/hma; ./hma-start -r'
subprocess.Popen(hma, shell=True)
```

But you can also do this without `shell=True`:

```
hma = ['/Desktop/hma/hma-start', '-r']
subprocess.Popen(hma)
```

If you wanna wait until the process finished, call `.communicate()` on the `Popen-Object`.

Comment: How do I use the Popen-Object?
Also when I use
    hma = ['/Desktop/hma/hma-start', '-r']
    subprocess.Popen(hma)
I get an error

Comment: Which error? Normally you do: `p = Popen(…, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE);`stdout, stderr = p.communicate()`

Comment: Well the whole reason that I need to use subprocess is because once hma is launched it won't let any other commands that follow it execute.

Comment: I guess your path ist just wrong: `/Desktop` doesn't exist on linux, did you mean `~/Desktop/hma`?

Comment: The path isn't wrong because I'm running it in root. I know that it isn't advised but I prefer to not have any restrictions. It's also a VM so it is easily fixed.